# How to collapse the Navigation Panel at the time of creation of new case/account?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I don't know if its possible to do so or not!

Comment: And what is your problem, what did you try? Can you show the code that you have till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally upto the end user to keep this collapsed/expanded. There is no setting as of today. [Submitted an Idea](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=bcfb71c7-c333-ea11-8454-0003ff68ba2f)

We don't have a Xrm client API to tweak this from javascript form events today. [Submitted an Idea](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=87e6e14d-c533-ea11-8454-0003ff68ba2f)

Also, doing any DOM manipulation in client side scripting is unsupported.